# Issue with jQuery Async File Upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

So I'm trying to implement based on the article here.
http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/12/23/async-file-upload-with-jquery-and-asp-net.aspx

But I am receiving an error that states:  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'ajaxFileUpload'"

It's like it isn't seeing the jquery.extend or something.

I've included all of the files, everything looks good until I hit upload. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

It is erroring here, on the $.ajaxFileUpload:

```
 $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url: '../../Handlers/AjaxFileUploader.ashx',
            secureuri: false,
            fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { name: 'logan', id: 'id' },
            success: function (data, status) {
                if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                    if (data.error != '') {
                        alert(data.error);
                    } else {
                        alert(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data, status, e) {
                alert(e);
            }
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308260 please read this article if i may help you

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly as it is? Are you sure you included Jquery.js file? Where is it getting the error? Which line/page. Is it getting it on server side or client side(I assume client side)

Comment: I did copy the code, did an include on the .js files and the .css as well. My regular jQuery stuff is working, but this extenstion isn't.  Thanks. Oh and this isn't an IE only thing, it fails in FF too. But FF just swallows the error.

Answer (score 0):

Since your js is working, it could be that the file is missing.

Use firebug in FF and check in the Net tab. Look for the plugin's js file.

Make sure your path is correct and that the js file is actually being loaded.

Comment: It is there, but running it through Firebug gives me this error. $.ajaxFileUpload is not a function
ajaxFileUpload()default.aspx (line 506)
onclick()onclick (line 2)
event = click clientX=459, clientY=59

Comment: Oddly enough the .ajaxFileUpload shows up in the intellisense of VS.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be something funky with Visual Studio 2010 on my localhost. Next time I restarted the IDE it was working. No idea what the issue was.